# DateTime.ParseExact throwing format exception for format "H"

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime, datetime-format

In the code below,keyValuePair[0] is a string representation of an hour 0-23,ie `keyValuePair[0] == "2"` to represent 2:00 AM. 13 for 1:00PM. I want to be able displaying this value in both 12 and 24 hour clocks.

**an example:**

`keyValuePair[0] == 13` makes the value `time` equal "13:00" OR 1:00 PM" depending on the current Culture.

```
time = DateTime.ParseExact(keyValuePair[0], "H", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("t");
```

This works only when keyValuePair[0] has a 2 digit value,and I switch the format `"H"` to `"HH"`.However, my input can possibly be 1 digit input.When the input is 1 digit long and I use the format`"HH"`  I get an invalid format exception.

Perhaps there is a simpler way to do this? I guess I should just use "HH" and add a zero to  keyValuePair[0]?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo.

Comment: If it is number why do you have to parse it as `DateTime`? You can parse it as number and add to date `new DateTime().AddHours(int.Parse(keyValuePair[0]))` and than format whatever way you want...

Comment: There does get to be a point where it stops making sense to use DateTime.Parse().   Sure this ought to be `time = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(keyValuePair[0]), 0, 0);`

Comment: Ok, I will try these alternatives. Perhaps write them as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
time = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, Convert.ToInt32(keyValuePair[0]), 0, 0).ToString("t");
```

Answer (score 0):

"H" doesn't work because a single-character format string is assumed to be a [standard date and time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but "H" is not one of the standard formats. To specify a [custom format string with a single specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers), prefix the specifier with "%":

```
time = DateTime.ParseExact(keyValuePair[0], "%H", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("t");
```

**Note:** Both `DateTime.ParseExact` and `new DateTime(1, 1, 1, h, 0, 0)` (Nimesh's answer) will validate that the specified hour is between 0 and 23. In contrast, `DateTime.AddHours(h)` and `new TimeSpan(h, 0, 0)` will accept values of `h` less than 0 or greater than 23.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `PadLeft(2, '0')` to achieve what you want !

```
time = DateTime.ParseExact(keyValuePair[0].PadLeft(2, '0'), "HH", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("t");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int input = int.Parse(keyValuePair[0]);
time = DateTime.Today.AddHours(input).ToString("t");
```